# MySQL Syntax Error - Trying to update row without deleting/creating a new primary key

Tags: php, mysql

After having my PHP script fail, I tried this and multiple variants of it, in SQL - and it tells me that my syntax is wrong.

`INSERT INTO qarows (questions, answers) VALUES(test, test) WHERE id='735'`

This is my database structure: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ot8cH.jpg

---

This is the PHP script I started with:

```
function updateDatabase($compare){
    $update = $this->dbh->prepare("
            INSERT INTO qarows (
            questions, answers, updateTimeUnicode, updateTimeNatural
            ) VALUES (
            :questions, :answers, :updateTimeUnicode, :updateTimeNatural
            ) WHERE id=:id
            ");
    $update->execute(array(
        ':questions' => $this->question, 
        ':answers' => $this->answer,
        ':updateTimeUnicode' => $this->updateTimeUnicode,
        ':updateTimeNatural' => $this->updateTimeNatural,
        ':id' => $this->id
        ));
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You cannot combine insert and where.

Comment: Quoting test "test" could help as well as removing where clausule from an insert statement.

Comment: Deleting parts of answered questions is bad for future visitors.

Comment: remember to accept answers when it indeed helped you

Comment: @Paul Will you suggest how to update my question, to get fewer downvotes - please?

Comment: Not sure this one can be saved from downvotes, if you hover over the downvotes control it explains "lack of research" is an example of when to downvote. A basic mySQL tutorial should have examples of replacing formal parameters like test with actual parameters, and the use cases for insert vs update.  Also, the exact error message is always preferred to a generic such as syntax error.  As you gain experience, you'll ask better questions.

Comment: If you have more questions about how the site works, check out meta stack overflow. http://meta.stackoverflow.com

Comment: @Paul I didn't know it would give info on hover, that's helpful. Thanks.

Comment: If you think that is cool try clicking the `mysql` tag that looks like a button underneath your question, then click learn more on the next page....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

syntax needs to be like this

update qarows set questions = 'something', answers = 'something else', updateTimeUnicode = 'whatever'  where id = 735;

Answer (score 0):

You cannot insert a row where that primary key (the id column) already exists, I believe what you want to do is update it:

```
UPDATE qarows SET questions = 'test', answers 'test' WHERE id='735'
```